# Are you able to create clean URLs with Wget?

Tags: wget, gnu

I'm attempting to create a mirror of a WordPress site with clean URLs (i.e. http://example.org/foo *not* http://example.org/foo.php). When Wget mirrors the site, it gives all pages and links a ".html" extension (i.e. http://example.org/foo.html).

Is it possible to set options for Wget to create a clean URL structure, so that the mirrored file corresponding to the page "http:example.org/foo" would be "/foo/index.html" and the link to that page would be "http:example.org/foo"? If so, how?

Comment: Do you own the original site you're trying to mirror? Why not just have clean URLs to begin with? Also, why are you trying to mirror the site to begin with? For performance purposes? Why not just just have a caching proxy in front of it?

Comment: Yes, I own it. The WP site does have clean URLs but I'm not able to get the mirrored site to have them.

It's an experiment. The goal is to increase performance, security, simplicity and maintainability. I'd like to be able to host WP sites at secret URLs and deploy a static version to an auto-scaling CDN of some sort. Since the public facing site would be just static files, there would be little security risk and the CDN would handle scaling.

Comment: There are application firewalls which also do caching such as CloudFlare that achieve most of this with much less complexity. Your site won't be completely offline but unless you're planning to hide absolutely all dynamic content (ie. contact forms, comment forms, related article lists, etc.) you're not going to be able to completely obscure your origin any way.

Comment: Thanks for that. CloudFlare looks interesting. I'd like to do some more research. My company uses Akamai and Jenkins. The use case of WordPress sites with "no dynamic content" (comment forms, etc.) is actually a pretty common one for us. I know there are advantages to the solution you suggest but I think there is a strong case for just taking a bunch of static files, dumping them on S3 and forgetting about them. Anyway, I'd still like to know if Wget is capable of doing what I'd like it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking for what is the default behaviour of Wget.

Wget will only add the extension to the local copy, if the `--adjust-extension` option has been passed to it. Quoting the man page for Wget:

```
   --adjust-extension
       If a file of type application/xhtml+xml or text/html is downloaded and the URL does not end with the regexp \.[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]?, this option will cause the suffix .html to be appended to the
       local filename.  This is useful, for instance, when you're mirroring a remote site that uses .asp pages, but you want the mirrored pages to be viewable on your stock Apache server.  Another good
       use for this is when you're downloading CGI-generated materials.  A URL like http://example.com/article.cgi?25 will be saved as article.cgi?25.html.
```

However, what you seem to be asking for, that Wget saves `example.org/foo` as `/foo/index.html` is actually the default option. If you're seeing some other output, you should post the complete output of Wget with the `--debug` switch.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and I feel absolutely "silly". I had been following a tutorial which suggested using the `--convert-links` option for some reason. I'm not sure why I didn't understand this. Couldn't be clearer: "...this option will cause the suffix ‘.html’ to be appended to the local filename"